# CBV overrides django-filter context

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm trying to implement [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) in my project but I've hit a roadblock :/ Somehow `filter instance` is getting removed from context..

```
class ListReservations(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = 'reservations/homepage.html'
    paginate_by = 25
    model = Reservation
    filterset_class = ReservationFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ListReservations, self).get_context_data()
        ctx['today'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m')
        return ctx
```

Results are still getting filtered, but don't have access to `{{filter.form}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by doing the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(ListReservations, self).get_context_data()
    ctx['today'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m')
    ctx['filter'] = self.get_filterset(self.get_filterset_class())
    return ctx
```

Hope it helps someone someday :)

Answer (score 1):

The super call for get_context_data should include kwargs:

`ctx = super(ListReservations, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`